# Inheriting class attributes without declaring attributes or better OOP

Tags: python, class, oop

I am attempting to construct classes to play out a game of MTG (A card game). I have three relevant classes: MTGGame(...), MTGCard(...), and AbilityList(). An object of MTGGame has several attributes about the player (turn, mana,..., deck).

A player must have a deck of cards to play, so I create a list of MTGCard objects for each player that is a deck, and create an MTGGame object for each from the respective decks. The cards have abilities, and when creating the cards I store abilities as functions/params into each MTGCard. **However**, I need the abilities to inherit and access methods/attributes from MTGGame and update them, but if I use `super().__init__`, then I will need to call my deck as a parameter for AbilityList when making MTGCards, which I wouldn't have yet.

*Can this be achieved? If not, any suggestions improving my OOP logic to achieve this task?*

I am aware that I can do something like this:

```
class MTGGame():

    def __init__(self, deck, turn = 0, mana = 0, lifeTotal = 20, cavalcadeCount = 0, hand = [], board = []):   
        self.turn = turn
        self.mana = mana
        self.lifeTotal = lifeTotal
        ...
    def gainLife(self, lifeGained):
        self.lifeTotal = self.lifeTotal +lifeGained
    def combatPhase(self):
        for card in self.board:
            card.attackingAbility()

class MTGCard():

    def __init__(self, name, CMC, cardType, power, toughness, castedAbility, attackingAbility, activatedAbility, canAttack = False):
        ....
        self.attackingAbility = attackingAbility

Class abilityList():

    def healersHawkAbility(self, lifeAmt):
        MTGGame.gainLife(lifeAmt)
```

But this would affect all instances of MTGGame, not the specific MTGGame object this would've been called from. I'd like it to simply update the specific object in question. I'd like to do something like this but I don't know how abilityList methods could access MTGGame attributes/methods ('AbilityList' object has no attribute 'gainLife'):

```
Class abilityList():

    def healersHawkAbility(self, lifeAmt):
        #How do I access methods/attributes in MTGGame from here? self?
        self.gainLife(lifeAmt)

aL = abilityList()
#One example card:
card1 = MTGCard("Healers Hawk",1,'Creature',1,1, aL.nullAbility(), aL.healersHawkAbility, aL.nullAbility())
whiteDeck = [list of constructed MTGCard() objects, card1, card2,...,cardLast]
player1 = MTGGame(whiteDeck)
...

#Call the ability in a method contained in MTGGame:
player1.combatPhase()
#Would call something like this inside
card.attackingAbility()

#Which may refer to card.healersHawkAbility() since we stored healersHawkAbility() as an attribute for that MTGCard, 
#and would declare gainLife(), which refers to self.lifeTotal or player1.lifeTotal in this case.
```

Comment: Having your `ability_list` class inherit from `MTGGame` doesn't make a any sense

Comment: Fair enough! But I'm not aware of how else one would execute a method in the AbilityList class, stored in a MTGCard object, to affect an attribute of an MTGGame instance like lifeTotal (for example)?

Comment: @MarcoSousa _Fair enough! But I'm not aware of how else one would execute a method in the AbilityList class, stored in a MTGCard object, to affect an attribute of an MTGGame instance like lifeTotal (for example)?_ Can you be more specific?

Comment: Maybe? I updated it to provide an example of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm  attempting to call a method (which happens to be from the AbilityList class), and have that method update an attribute in an MTGGame object's attribute (such as lifeTotal). I don't know how to access self.lifeTotal in a MTGGame object (for example) from the AbilityList function other than super()_, which doesn't work, since an input for MTGGame is the deck we're making when creating the abilities and cards.

Comment: Hmm, this seems like a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382) to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an excellent start and clearly you have already thought a lot of this through. However, you haven't thought through the relationship between the classes.

First thing to note:
`MTGGame.gainLife(lifeAmt)` is a method call accessed via the class rather than an instance. This means that the self paramter is not actually filled in i.e. you will get an error becuase your method expects 2 arguments but only receive one.
What you perhaps meant to do is the following:

```
class MTGGame:

    lifeTotal = 20 # Notice this is declared as a class variable

    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def healersHawkAbility(cls, lifeGained):
        cls.lifeTotal = cls.lifeTotal + lifeGained
```

However, this requires class variables which here defeats the point of having an instance.

Your naming throughout the program should suggest that your classes are a little off.
For instance `player1 = MTGGame()`. Is player a game? No, of course not. So actually you might want to rename your class MTGGame to Player to make it clear it refers to the player, not the game. A seperate class called MTGGame will probably need to be created to manage the interactions between the players e.g. whose turn it is, the stack holding the cards whilst resolving.

The main focus of your question: how to deal with the cards accessing the game/player object.

Cards should be able to access instances of the player and game classes, and if the player has a is_playing attribute, the card should not have this. The rule of thumb for inheritance is 'is a'. Since card 'is not a' player, it should not inherit from it or MTGGame. Instead, card should be like this for example:

```
game = RevisedMTGGame()
player1 = Player()
player2 = Player()

class Card:
    def __init__(self, name, text, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
        self.cost = cost
        self.owner = None
        self.game = None

class Creature(Card):
    def __init__(self, name, text, cost, power, toughness):
        super().__init__(self, name, text, cost)
        self.power = power
        self.toughness = toughness
    def lifelink(self):
        self.owner.heal(self.power) # NOTE: this is NOT how I would implement lifelink, it is an example of how to access the owner

healersHawk = Creature("Healer's Hawk", "Flying, Lifelink", 1, 1, 1)
healersHawk.game = game
healersHawk.owner = player1
```

You can see from this incomplete example how you can set up your cards easily, even with complex mechanics, and as the base classes have been defined you can avoid repitition of code. You might want to look into the event model in order to implement the lifelink mechanic, as an example. I wish you luck in continuing your game!

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yeah I accidently clicked the answer button :P

Comment: Well, thank you for that mistake! This was very helpful! Helped clean up my OOP classes and answered the question of accessing player attributes from other classes (the usage of self.owner was a key intuition).